# How can i fit a image into a frame without losing ratio using PHP

Tags: php, image

Actually, Here user can upload any size image to fit into any frame which i have. I want to fit that image into a frame without losing ratio.

Example:

[This image is not fitting with my php code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHoLI.png)

My code is

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($img1);
        $outputImage = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

        // set background to white
        //$white = imagecolorallocate($outputImage, 255, 255, 255);
        //imagefill($outputImage, 0, 0, $white);
        list($width1, $height1) = getimagesize($img2);
        $info1 = getimagesize($img1);
        $info2 = getimagesize($img2);
        $extension1 = image_type_to_extension($info1[2]);
        $extension2 = image_type_to_extension($info2[2]);
        if($extension1=='.jpeg') {
        $first = imagecreatefromjpeg($img1);
        } else { 
        $first = imagecreatefrompng($img1);
        }
        if($extension2=='.jpeg') {
        $second = imagecreatefromjpeg($img2);
        } else { 
        $second = imagecreatefrompng($img2);
        }
        $ratio = $width1 / $height1;
        $targetWidth = 300 * $ratio;
        //echo $targetWidth;
        //imagecopyresized ( resource $dst_image , resource $src_image , int $dst_x , int $dst_y , int $src_x , int $src_y , int $dst_w , int $dst_h , int $src_w , int $src_h )
        imagecopyresampled($outputImage,$first,0,0,0,0, $width, $height, $width, $height);
        imagecopyresampled($outputImage,$second,110,75,0,0, $targetWidth, 300, $width1, $height1);
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to achieve that you must detect the frame image and source image dimensions
re size the source image to fit the frame image dimensions. 
note that to avoid ratio problems we will detect if the source image wide image or tall image (landscape or portrait)
if width > height then set the width to the width of frame and calculate the new height based on main ratio
if height > width
set height to frame height and calculate the new width
this is sample implementation code

```
<?
$src  = imagecreatefromjpeg('source.jpg');//source image path
$frame = imagecreatefrompng('frame.png');//frame image
$sourceWidth = imagesx($src); // source image width
$sourceHeight = imagesy($src); // image image height
$frameWidth = imagesx($frame);//get frame width
$frameHeight = imagesy($frame);//get frame height
$NewImage = imagecreatetruecolor($frameWidth,$frameHeight);//the new image
$bg_color = imagecolorallocate ($NewImage, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($NewImage, 0, 0, $bg_color);//set background to white
if($sourceHeight >= $sourceWidth){
$newHeight=$frameHeight;// set height to frame height
$newWidth=intval($frameWidth*$sourceWidth/$sourceHeight);//calculate the new width  
imagecopyresampled($NewImage, $src, intval(($frameWidth-$newWidth)/2),0,0,0,$newWidth, $newHeight, $sourceWidth, $sourceHeight);//insert source image to new image at the center
} else {
$newWidth=$frameWidth;;// set width to frame width
$newHeight=intval($frameHeight*$sourceHeight/$sourceWidth);//calculate the new height 
imagecopyresampled($NewImage, $src,0,intval(($frameHeight-$newHeight)/2),0,0,$newWidth, $newHeight,$sourceWidth, $sourceHeight);//insert source image to new image at the center
}
imagecopyresampled($NewImage, $frame, 0,0, 0,0, $frameWidth, $frameHeight, $frameWidth, $frameHeight);//copy frame imageto new image 
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagejpeg($NewImage);
?>
```

hope this would help.

Comment: Yes thanks, This helped me but only for a limitation.

Actually, When source image is small then frame has  white space inside own for top, right, left and bottom. but i also want to customize frame image for deleting that space and image should be fit inside the frame corner to corner.

Comment: if you want to fit the frame corner to corner you will lose the source image ratio. we have to add background to the source image.
to solve this problem you can use multiple frame image with different ratio let say one for landscape and another for portrait and detect witch one you will use based on the source image ratio.